# Does anyone know what's wrong with mysql query?

Tags: php

```
   define("QUERY","INSERT INTO rft_media_invention . " " (dbInventionFileType, dbStaffId, dbInventionFileName, dbInventionFileContent)" . "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Its always giving me this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in p3t\phpappfolder\public_php\cw\UC213.php on line 20

anyone knows if my query is fully correct?

Comment: There is a dot after `rft_media_invention` that doesn't belong in there, but after the quote

Comment: You've got the first dot and double quote reversed. `...O rft_media_invention . "`

Comment: Been ages since I did PHP, but this `. " "` looks like it should be `" . "`

Comment: From `. " " ` to ` " . "` .. could you try that?

Comment: what's the point in defining queries as constants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax errors:

```
define("QUERY","INSERT INTO rft_media_invention . " " (dbIn etc...
                                               ^^^^^
```

should probably be

```
define("QUERY","INSERT INTO rft_media_invention " . " (dbIn etc...
```

which also begs the question of why you're concatenating the strings to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you need to transpose the first period and the quote that follows it:

```
...rft_media_invention . " "
```

should be

```
...rft_media_invention " . "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  Your comma after rtf_media_invention should go after the double quotes, not before.

Answer (score 0):

define("QUERY","INSERT INTO rft_media_invention " . "(dbInventionFileType, dbStaffId, dbInventionFileName, dbInventionFileContent)"